# Java setting up prepared statements

Tags: java, class, structure, prepared-statement

This is a question relating more to coding standards than anything else.

The problem that I am having is that I am struggling to use my prepared statements as a class/constructor (I am from an informix background btw java is still new to me).

Usually when I code I like to keep scripting out of the main block as much as possible and then call in functions as I need them like in the example I will show. I am also exaggerating the structure with lots of forward slashes.

```
public class Script {

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// start main
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Script Is Starting");    // basic message

        classCONN conn = new classCONN();            // connect class
        Connection cnct = null;                      // connect variable
                                                     //
        try {                                        // try connect
           conn.func_driverCheck();                  //
           cnct = conn.func_dbConnect();             //
        } catch(SQLException log) {                  //
           System.out.println(log);                  //
        }                                            //

        *i would like to call the prepare*
        *statements function once for the*
        *rest of the script*

        classSQL sql = new classSQL();               // prepare statements
        sql.func_prep(cnct);                         //

        users_sel.setString(1, "zoh");               // insert with prepared
        users_sel.setString(2, "my");                // statements
        users_sel.setString(3, "goodness");          //
        row = users_sel.executeQuery();              //

    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// end main

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// start classes
    class classCONN {

       public void func_driverCheck() {*code to check driver*}

       public Connection func_dbConnect() {*code to connect to db*}

    }

    class classSQL {

       *I would like to prepare my statements here*

       public void f_prep(Connection cnct) {
           lv_sql = "INSERT INTO users " +
                    "VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
           PreparedStatement users_ins = cnct.prepareStatement(lv_sql);
       }

    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// end classes

}
```

so my question being is there a way to get code like this to work so that the statements are prepared and then I can executeUpdate them from inside different classes or in the main or anything like that without actually preparing the statements completely in the main block

Comment: You may want to have a look by [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: what's the difference between stackoverflow and codereview?

Comment: Codereview is for having your (working) code reviewed including suggestions for best practice.

Comment: Oh kwl, I didn't realize how vast stack exchange was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have come up with an answer to my own question and I would just like to post it here in case anyone can benefit from it or has anything to add to it because that's what this community is for.

```
public class Prog {

    // static variables ---------------------------------------------------
    static Connection conn;
    static ResultSet row;

    // main ---------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       // connect to db ---------------------------------------------------
       try {
          DBConnect cl_conn = new DBConnect();
          conn = cl_conn.f_connect();
       } catch(Exception log) {
          System.out.println("FAIL")
       }

       // prepare statements ----------------------------------------------
       SQLPrep prep = new SQLPrep(conn);

       // execute statement 01 --------------------------------------------
       try {
          prep.users_sel.setInt(1, 2);           // pass values to stmnt
          row = prep.users_sel.executeQuery();   // execute stmnt
       } catch(SQLException log) {
          System.out.println("FAIL");
       }

    }

}

class DBConnect {
   ***code to connect to db***
}

// all prepared stmnts in one place ----------------------------------------
class SQLPrep {

   static PreparedStatement users_sel = null;    // select from users
   static PreparedStatement access_sel = null;   // select from access

   try {

      sp_sql = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE u_id = ?";
      users_sel = conn.prepareStatement(sp_sql);

      sp_sql = "SELECT * FROM ACCESS WHERE a_id = ?";
      access_sel = conn.prepareStatement(sp_sql);

   } catch(SQLException log) {
      System.out.println("FAIL");
   }

}
```

This may look strange to some people but I find this to be a very clean and tidy way of structuring code (keeping as much code out of the main as possible). Even the block where the statement is executed can be moved into a separate function and would only need to be passed 'prep.users_prep' to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have greate Example on how to use PreparedStatement.

[JDBC PreparedStatement Example – Select List Of The Records](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/)

Comment: this is a great place for me to start, not quite what I had in mind but this gives me an idea of how to achieve the flow that I would like